# Vuejs v-for infinite update loop using Array.prototype.reverse()

Tags: loops, vuejs2

I have such an error I can not solve in any way

[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function. found in

in component use

```
    <div  v-for="item in items">
         {{item.title}}
    <div>
.................
    <div  v-for="item in items.reverse()">
         {{item.title}}
    <div>

export default {
   name: "component-name"
   data(){
        return { 
            items: []
            }
       }
 }
```

....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Array.prototype.reverse` **actually modifies the array it's applied to**.

Vue picks up this change and triggers both `v-for` to re-evaluate, triggering another `.reverse()`. That triggers Vue to re-render, causing it to `.reverse()` *etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc*...

To solve this, use a `computed` property on a shallow copy of `items[]` (e.g. using `Array` destructuring `[...this.items]` for the reversed list:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    itemsReverse() {
      return [...this.items].reverse()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="item in items">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
  <ul v-for="item in itemsReverse">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```